# On vs at ( computer monitor)

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which is grammatically correct?

The information is ***on*** the top right of your screen (computer)

or

The information is ***at*** the top right of your screen

Comment: Use **on** to describe things attached to the monitor, like a sticky note. If you're describing what a web page or an application displays, it's better to say to describe it using what the application or web page says.

Comment: @FeliniusRex It says, "on/at the top of your **screen**", not "monitor". It's clear both ways

Comment: The word *on* means to stack something in a physical dimension. Also *monitor* is stated in the title. Also, don’t be a jerk. The fact that someone left a comment means that some clarity is lacking.

Comment: You should use **at** because you are talking about a particular area within 
the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these are fine. People probably have individual preferences, but neither is better or worse than the other and they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "**at** the top right of the screen" is slightly more idiomatic, though **on** is acceptable.

Without the "top right" part, it would have to be "the information is **on** your screen".

Answer (score 0):

We think that both of them are grammatically correct, you can use any of them and it will make perfect sense. However, we think that "AT" sounds quite better.

Comment: We do? Who is this we you speak of?